# Which to use? int32_t vs uint32_t

Tags: c++, c

How do I know if I should be using int32_t or uint32_t?

I have found a few descriptions of them (signed/ unsigned) but that hasn't helped me understand this much coming from a java background. So under which scenarios would I use these two options? Specifically I need a variable to hold a 32 bit binary value, but a general answer would be fine as well.

Comment: Is that 32 binary value signed, or unsigned? Might it ever be negative? Will you be passing it to other functions that expect signed or unsigned values?

Comment: Java always uses signed integers and works quite happily with that. So until you understand things better, use int32_t.